# files saved from custom options 'file' delete after x days

Tags: magento2, custom-options, file

I have products where the custom option 'file' is selected'

all those files are saved in the folder "pub/media/custom_options/quote/x/x"

the names are difficult to track:
1VbvhQMwivy8Crdf3kc26dsrlkLBMUNP

the files should only be there for max 30 days. Is there a way to set this?